# Nginx default backend custom error page not rendering properly

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have the Nginx ingress controller running in my cluster with a default backend set up.

I'm using a wildcard cert as my default SSL certificate, and everything works fine.

`foo.example.com`, `foo.example.com/one` etc, all point to my custom error page. However, I've noticed that `foo.example.com/one/` even though it points to the custom error page, does not render the CSS at all, only the index.html.

It's quite interesting and I'm just wondering if anyone might have experienced this before and how it was resolved.

Comment: Hello, for reproduction purposes please add the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also I'd reckon you can create an issue on the [nginx-ingress github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues) page if you suspect that this is a bug.